# Static Homepage on Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I have a static html page on domain `http://www.example.com`, then i add subdomain on it and install wordpress. so it should look like this for the wordpress domain `http://wpdomain.example.com`.

but what i want is `http://www.example.com` serves as homepage with all the static html page that i created before intact, and the wordpress serves as blog.

and the post i created at wordpress would have permalink like `http://www.example.com/category/post-title` and only the blog page that will have an url : `http://wpdomain.example.com`

how can I achieve that? because when I'm trying to change in general setting for the homepage url to `http://www.example.com`, now i can't access my wp-admin page at all error 500, but i still can open up the blog page now at `http://www.example.com/wpdomain` but when i using url `http://wpdomain.example.com` it will redirect me back to `http://www.example.com`

Comment: This is really not ideal because of more than one reason. Why don't you just have them both on the same domain? It would be very simple to achieve.

Comment: the reason is with static html i can speed up the load process, and while the blog only serve SEO purpose.

Comment: You dont need a subdomain for that.

Comment: yes, i understand I don't need subdomain for that, it's just I'm doing this for experimenting the effect on the site SEO.

Answer (score 1):

you can use a .htaccess file on your server to redirect the users when they try to access a page who does'nt exist like this below

```
errordocument 404 /404.php
```

this is the 404.php file:

```
<?php 

// get the url of the page who give an 404 error 'page doesn't exist'
$url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

$url=substr($url,1,strlen($url));   

$path = '/wpdomain/'.$url;

$content = file_get_contents($path)

echo $content;

?>
```

---

when a user will try to access at `example.com/category/post-title`

he will be redirect on the `404.php` page.

`404.php` will keep the url that the user requested and will show the content of

`example.com/wpdomain/category/post-title`

Comment: thanks for the answer, but what i try to achieve is that for my post permalink would look like this http://www.example.com/category/post-title instead of http://www.example.com/wpdomain/category/post-title is that achievable?

Comment: I will try this method first, thanks for the answer :D